# continue insert statement even though exception is generated

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to execute below query and during that one constraint violation exception is generated and due to that insert statement is terminated.

I want suppose from 10 records 9 records are clean then insertion will done for 9.right now statement is terminated and no insertion is performed.

I am using SQL Server 2012 and i do not want to rollback transaction and Insert ignore command is not there in SQL server and i do not want to insert data which contains error.i just want to insert clean data.

**Query :**

```
INSERT INTO rcmschargepostingmastertable 
            (clinicid, 
             clinicsiteid, 
             appointmentid, 
             patientid
             ) 
SELECT clinicid, 
       clinicsiteid, 
       appointmentid, 
       patientid, 

FROM   #tempautopostbulkchargepostingmastertable
```

Comment: I believe this question gets the award for the hardest to read code sample that contributes the least to understanding and solving the question. *CONGRATS!*  Now tell us what your constraint error was so we can answer the question.

Comment: SSIS can do this (because it's pipeline-based), but not T-SQL (because it's wholly transactional).  Not directly anyway...

Comment: code is simple but i think it was not proper formatted.i do not want to use SSIS.

Comment: No, the code is largely irrelevant.  Listing all of those columns tells us nothing important.  Telling us the error *would* tell us something important.

Comment: i have already told  that i want to ignore any sql error and want to continue insertion for clean records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do what you stated in your comment:

> i want to ignore any sql error and want to continue insertion for
>   clean records

SQL Server doesn't have any pure SQL mechanism for doing this.  Your only choice is to use one of the proposed work-arounds (SSIS, WHERE clause).

One work-around that hasn't been mentioned because it's the worst performance-wise, but at least it's one that you haven't shot down, is to replace your set-based insert with a cursor that does the inserts one row at a time.

Then you could put the single-row insert in a TRY block, and if it errors, the cursor will skip it and move on to the next one.

Comment: This is the only answer so far that "solves" the problem.  Every DBA sobs quietly to themselves when the idea of using a CURSOR comes up -- but I guess that is a way to "solve it".  I'm going to just not insert records that cause errors, but to each their own.

Comment: I do not want to use cursor or any other loop.if I am not able to find any other solution I will go with where clause for known errors.

Comment: A WHERE clause is your best solution.   As I said, it is not possible to tell SQL to ignore records that would cause errors and just insert the ones that won't.

Answer (score 1):

*I do not want to insert data which contains error.i just want to insert clean data.*

Then you need to identify and filter out the bad data/constraint violating records before inserting into target table which will make your life easier.

```
  ........
  modifiedbyid 
FROM   #tempautopostbulkchargepostingmastertable 
Where some_column <> 'bad data'
```

Since you are using SQL Server 2012 you can use [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh230993.aspx) to identify and filter out the bad data

Comment: All errors are not known.it may be run time error like constraint violation,data truncation or any other SQL error.i want to ignore that data and want to continue exceution

Comment: constraint violating records can be filtered out in `Where` clause

Comment: constraint violation is just one error.there may be so many other errors an d i can not filter 10 columns using where clause.